# Fix bone symmetry

Tags: armature, bones

I'm having an issue where some bones on my armature aren't perfectly symmetrical with the corresponding bones on the other side. Is there a way to fix this without having to delete the bones?

To further explain, the hand bones on the rig aren't lined up correctly. Normally if a bone is symmetrical to another bone, both bones will have the same Y and Z locations and inverse X locations (for both the head and tail). This is not present in the rig and would be tedious to fix manually.
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Unfortunately we can't help fix it without any images or blend file https://blend-exchange.com :)

Comment: First, check bone names that should be symmetrical-- they should have the same names, followed by either .R or .L to indicate side.  Then, select one side of your armature in edit mode-- a box select makes this easier-- and use the "symmetrize" operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nathan's comment sums the fix up pretty well. Just be sure to select the bone you want to keep in place first as the unselected bone's location will be replaced with the selected bone's mirrored location.